# Returning data from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my application, I have `textView`. when I click it a fragment shows up, the fragment contains an `autoCompleteTextView` of search googleApi address and a recycleView that contains a list of history locations.

my problem is that when I click on one of the address (from `autoCompleteTextView` or recycleView) I want to return the chosen address and to update the textView at the caller activity.

Here is the code of the custom fragment:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.AutoSizeableTextView;
import android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.facebook.places.model.PlaceInfoRequestParams;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.moneytime.busy.R;

import com.moneytime.busy.activities.ChooseAddressActivity;
import com.moneytime.busy.adapters.PlaceArrayAdapter;
import com.moneytime.busy.adapters.PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter;
import com.moneytime.busy.application.Analytics;
import com.moneytime.busy.application.CustomApplication;
import com.moneytime.busy.base.BaseActivity;
import com.moneytime.busy.base.BaseFragment;
import com.moneytime.busy.custom.CustomCompleteTextView;
import com.moneytime.busy.custom.ErrorDescriptor;
import com.moneytime.busy.network.NetworkManager;
import com.moneytime.busy.network.interfaces.MissionsNetworkResponseListener;
import com.moneytime.busy.network.requests.LastMissionsRequest;
import com.moneytime.busy.network.response.Location;
import com.moneytime.busy.network.response.Mission;
import com.moneytime.busy.adapters.UserLocationsAdapter;
import com.moneytime.busy.utils.LocationUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LocationsFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}


    private AutoCompleteTextView mCompleteTextView;
    private ImageView closeBtn;
    private RecyclerView rvLocationList;
    private UserLocationsAdapter locationsHisAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Location> locationsDataList;
    private PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter aComLocationsAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 //   private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71, 136));
    public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = "LOCATION_EXTRA";


    public static LocationsFragment getInstance(LatLng mLastKnownLocation) {

        LocationsFragment fragment = new LocationsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(EXTRA_LOCATION, mLastKnownLocation);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_loctions_user, container, false);


        initUiViews(v);
        initUIFunctionality();

        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        rvLocationList.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        getLocationsHistory();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    private void initUiViews(final View v) {

        mCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aCompleteTextView);
        closeBtn=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.closebtn) ;
        rvLocationList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.locations_recyclerView);
        rvLocationList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((getActivity())));

    }

    private void initUIFunctionality() {

        closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCompleteTextView.setText("");
            }
        });

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(getContext())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .build();

        aComLocationsAdapter = new PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(getContext(), mGoogleApiClient, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);
        mCompleteTextView.setAdapter(aComLocationsAdapter);
    }

    //Check duplicates items in list of address
    public boolean contains(ArrayList<Location> list, String location) {
        if (list.size() == 0)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getAddress().equals(location))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Return List of History of address for the recycleView
    public void getLocationsHistory() {
        NetworkManager.getInstance().getCompletedOrders(new LastMissionsRequest(0), new MissionsNetworkResponseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onNetworkError(String errorMessage, int errorCode) {

                if (errorCode == 999) {
                    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).showNoInternetDialog();
                } else {
                    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).showNoInternetDialog();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNetworkSuccess(List<Mission> missionList) {
                locationsDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                int count = 0;
                for (Mission mission : missionList) {

                    if (count < 5) {
                        if (!contains(locationsDataList, mission.getDeliveryLocation().getAddress())) {
                            locationsDataList.add(mission.getDeliveryLocation());
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

                }
                locationsHisAdapter = new UserLocationsAdapter(getActivity(), locationsDataList);
                rvLocationList.setAdapter(locationsHisAdapter);
                //locationsHisAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not do a quick search on Google? This question was asked many and many times here in Stackoverflow and there are many guides online that covers this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that fragment belongs to an activity called MainActivity (otherwise just change the name on my example):

on MainActivity.class:

```
public void updateWhateverYouWantOnMainActivity(String whateverAddress){
  //update activity stuff here
}
```

on your Fragment:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateWhateverYouWantOnMainActivity(yourSelectedAddress);
```

**EDIT:**

You can also create an interface:

```
public interface OnAddressChangedListener{
    onAddressChanged(String newAddress);
}
```

Then, when creating the fragment, vou can pass in the caller activity as an interface implementation:

On your activity, when creating the fragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setOnAddressChangedListener(new OnAddressChangedListener(){
   @Override
   public void onAddressChanged(String newAddress){
      //update activity stuff here
   }

});
```

Your fragment:

```
public void setOnAddressChangedListener(OnAddressChangedListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   this.listener.onAddressChanged(yourSelectedAddress);
}
```

Comment: Easiest way but not the most right. In this way you create a permanent link between Fragment and the MainActivity and it is not a good practice. The best way (and the most clean) is to use an Interface/Listener to share between them. What about if the Fragment is opened from a different Activity?

Answer (score -1):

Create interface

```
 interface ISomeAction extends Serializable{
        void sendAddress(String address);
    }
```

In your `LocationsFragment`

```
 private ISomeAction iSomeAction;
    public static LocationsFragment getInstance(LatLng mLastKnownLocation,ISomeAction iSomeAction) {
args.putSerializable("interface", iSomeAction);
    //other code
    }
```

in `onCreateView`

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
iSomeAction = (ISomeAction) bundle.getSerializable("interface");
```

on your click or other action

```
iSomeAction.sendAddress("");
```

implement `ISomeAction` in your `activity`

```
@Override
    public void sendAddress(String address) {
     //Your action such as settext to textview
    }
```

Comment: Passing Activity as serializable doesn't make sens at all ... obviously after deserialization you will get different and not valid instance of the Activity

Comment: its the only activity who opens up this fragment

Comment: @Selvin I have tested above solution and it works. You can try it.

Comment: @Selvin your downvote is based on an assumption. Have you even tried mine solution?

Comment: Same as I never tried to stub myself with the knife. This solution is bad by definition.

Comment: [1. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = pl.selvin.terribleidea.MainActivity)` on pressing home button .... 2. not working after rotation ...](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/4d00f9a58a9fc8e3dc074601a3e33144)

Comment: @Selvin Thank you for taking the time and pointing out the flaws. appreciate it :)